# In ruby, how might I find all Files between two dates

Tags: ruby, file, last-modified

I'm very surprised I couldn't find an answer to this question, but I need to select all files modified between Time.now and 1.day.ago. Obviously I'm not expecting an 'ago' operator when dealing with the ruby File or FileUtil classes, but if somebody showed me one I wouldn't be surprised. :)

The other way would be an array function I think...perhaps involving the '<=>' operator which I have never used

Comment: It depends what the file structure of the files you're considering is like. Are they all in one directory, or are they in various directories, how many levels deep, etc. If they're all in the same directory, do you want to analyze _every_ file or only those of a particular file type or extension?

Comment: In this case, its a flat list of file names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this? (untested):

```
selected_files = Dir.glob("*.pdf").select do |file|
  mtime = File.mtime(file)

  # if in a rails environment:
  # (1.day.ago .. Time.now).cover?(mtime)

  # if not in rails environment but want to use that code do this before that line:
  # require 'active_support/all'

  # else do the math:
  # mtime > (Time.now - 86400) and mtime < Time.now
end
```

Comment: Wow nice one! I'm about to publish my hack, this looks interesting and more presentable to other developers

Comment: @coloradoblue There you go, only searches pdf files.